# Syntax errror with arrow function

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am starting to work with protractor using jasmine, but I am instantly getting an 'unexpected token' error when it parses my config that uses arrow an arrow function. Does anyone know what I might be missing? Dependency? It's on a new macbook.I didn't have this problem on my old pc.

```
  exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  capabilities: env.capabilities,
  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,
  specs: env.specs,
  allScriptsTimeout: 30 * 10000,

 onPrepare: async () => {
     if (!global.jasmineRequire) {
         var jasmineRequire = require('jasmine-core');
         if (typeof jasmineRequire.interface !== 'function') {
            throw "not able to load real jasmineRequire"
        }
        global.jasmineRequire = jasmineRequire;
    }
    require('jasmine-promises'); await browser.get(env.baseUrl + 
    '#!/login');



   macs-iMac:e2etest AchieveIt$ protractor conf.js
   [08:03:45] E/configParser - Error code: 105
   [08:03:45] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading 
   configuration file conf.js
   [08:03:45] E/configParser - 
   /Users/mac/achieveit/E2ETests/e2etest/conf.js:13
   onPrepare: async ()=> {
               ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
   at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE UPDATE**

Never mind, I see you're using an object now. What is your compiler? I think your compiler is not compiling the es6 correctly. Make sure you have all your node modules installed correctly whether it's globally or locally. Your code should be valid, see this fiddle: https://es6console.com/j20jir0j/

**UPDATE**

Even in es6, you syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
onPrepare = async () => {
```

**OLD for TS**

That's not valid typescript and shouldn't work anywhere.

Change your line to:

```
onPrepare = (): async => {
```

Or if you don't need lexical scope:

```
onPrepare(): async {
```

Comment: I'm not using typescript. at least i didn't intend to

Comment: Even with es6, your syntax is invalid. Try:

onPrepare = async () => {

Comment: Actually I just realized you're using an object. The problem must be with your compiler. See this fiddle, should be correct: https://es6console.com/j20jir0j/ Make sure you're using a prober es6 compiler

Comment: that makes sense, but when i change to es2015 i'm getting a similar error: "syntax error: unexpected token function"

Comment: Hmm I tried it on all the compilers and it passed on all except Traceur. Can you include your whole file?

Comment: Here's a link to the full config file:
https://es6console.com/j20llzgh/

Comment: In the example link you have an extra semi-colon on the second-last line :). When I removed it, it compiled, see: https://es6console.com/j20lzsoh/

Comment: there must be something wrong with my local machine then, because i'm still getting the error in the console when i run protractor conf.js

Comment: Which version of protractor are you using? Also which version of node and npm are on your machine? And which compiler? It sounds like there is some incompatibility with your toolchain somewhere

Comment: protractor: 5.1.1
node: 6.10.2
npm: 3.10.10
babel-polyfill 6.23.0